# Docusign Template Modification

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible for one docusign admin account's template to be modified by another docusign admin account when the first admin account created the template and shared with the second admin account.

Under the Preferences-->Personal Info --> Sharing menu seems like the "Filter by Name    Filter. Check the users who will be able to see and act on this user's folders " is all uncheked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question, Yes, it is possible if the second user is also admin , and as by default all shared templates are shared with other admins.